# ScrollView inside RecyclerView won't scroll

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make a `LinearLayout` (to which I'm adding items dynamically) scrollable inside a scrollable `RecyclerView`. On startup, I can see a little scrollbar initially (indicating it's a scrollable view, fades in seconds). Tried appCompat NestedScrollView as well as enabling `nestedScrollingEnabled`, with no success. How can I make the `LinearLayout` scrollable inside the `RecyclerView`?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <ScrollView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="300dp"
      android:fillViewport="true"
      android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">
      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/playerlist_linear"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
          android:orientation="vertical">
      </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

RecyclerView code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/messagesListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>
```

UPDATE: I found out that scrolling does indeed work, but only if I spam the mouse or tap really fast inside the scrollview. It kind of gets focused and allows scrolling as long as mouse is held down. Really strange.

Comment: Add your RecylerView layout code...

Comment: Added RecyclerView code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by adding a line to rafsanahmad007's solution:

```
    ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
    scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                         // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view

                   view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                   view.onTouch(motionEvent);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

I'm not sure that's how `View.onTouch` is called on Java, as I'm developing with Xamarin.Android (C#).  It should be pretty similar.

Comment: you should mark the Correct Answer and upvote the answer that helps you...that's what the stackoverflow community is for....Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try disabling the touch of recycler view when `scrollview` is being touched.

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                     // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
                    view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: It prevents the RecyclerView from scrolling when the ScrollView is touched. But the `ScrollView` itself still won't scroll.

Comment: I guess you have to return `false` from `onTouch`

Comment: Maybe. That would explain why I had to do `view.onTouch(motionEvent)`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an another way how the ScrollView can be scrolled inside RecyclerView viewHolder. I originally posted my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68506793/4569155), so you can look up my answer for how I can enabled the scroll of ScrollView inside RecyclerView. Hope this will help on someone who look up another answer.

But I also want to answer from the OP's question why there is a little scrollbar on the ScrollView. You can hide the scrollbar by adding `android:scrollbars="none"` in your ScrollView tag in xml layout and also remove `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` because it is no use in this case.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/playerlist_linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```